# Чтение и запись строк через StreamReader и StreamWriter. Программа закрывается

Tags: c#, файлы

Доброе утро.
Есть такой код

```js
            
            StreamReader keys =  new StreamReader(@"keys.txt");
            StreamReader add = new StreamReader(@"add.txt");//после этого действия выполнение переходит сразу в res.WriteLine(result);
            StreamWriter res = new StreamWriter(@"result.txt", true);
            string line1 = keys.ReadLine();
            string line2 = add.ReadLine();
            string result = line1 + line2;

            res.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Почему так? 
Этот код я для теста делал, потому думал запихнуть в цикл и склеивать строки. Из файла keys.txt берем строку и прибавляем к ней строку из add.txt, и пишем в result.txt, и так пока не кончатся строки в файлах. 
Собственно вопрос в том как мне сделать так что бы программа работала нормально а не переходила сразу в конец?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (StreamReader keys = new StreamReader(@"keys.txt"))
{
    using (StreamReader add = new StreamReader(@"add.txt"))
    {
        using (StreamWriter res = new StreamWriter(@"result.txt", true))
        {
            while (keys.Peek() != -1 || add.Peek() != -1)
            {
                res.WriteLine($"{keys.ReadLine()} {add.ReadLine()}");
            }
        }
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает только почему то не пишет в файл result.txt ничего, просто при прохождении действия ничего не происходит

Comment: @User12351259599491, странно, у меня записывает. попробуй удалить файл result, программа сама его создаст, и файл keys и add заново создай, предварительно копирую названия из программы, вдруг там где нибудь русский символ

Comment: Пробовал удалить, файл создается но ничего не пишет в него, пробовал делать так res.`WriteLine("sdfsdf");`, тоже не пишет, пробовал в другое место переносить в D:\result.txt, там тоже файл создается но ничего не пишется.

Comment: Я не знаю что это за шутки но у меня даже не записывает в файл вот так вот: `StreamWriter res = new StreamWriter(@"D:\result.txt", true);

            res.Write("sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf");`

Comment: @User12351259599491, попробуй еще вот так StreamWriter res = new StreamWriter(@"result.txt", false, Encoding.Default)

Comment: @User12351259599491, твои файлы лежат по пути \bin\Debug?

Comment: @User12351259599491, либо еще вот так using (StreamWriter res = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("result.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)))

Comment: Наверняка я где то туплю, но вот https://i.yapx.ru/GMTX9.gif гиф как я делаю и как ничего не происходит, хотя вроде бы должно писать в файл

Comment: Все равно не пишет(((

Comment: @User12351259599491, а вы точно копировали мой пример с using? из последнего примера: добавьте res.Close() и у вас будет запись. Вы не закрываете поток, поэтому запись не происходит. using автоматически делает закрывание, так автоматически вызывается res.Dispose() интерфейса IDisposeble.

Comment: Спасибо работает. А почему не сработало? И зачем нужны using?

Comment: @User12351259599491, using Это упрощенный способ освобождения создаваемых ресурсов. по факту это конструкция try{} catch(){} finally{ объект.Dispose(); } блок finally работает всегда, не зависимо от исхода работы программы, а значит объект освободится.

Comment: А когда закончатся строки в add.ReadLine(), можно как то переместится и снова начать получать строки с начала файла не закрывая поток?

Comment: @User12351259599491, установить позицию на начало keys.BaseStream.Position = 0;
add.BaseStream.Position = 0;